# Button missing positional argument 'self' in btn.pack()

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I've written a piece of code that uses tkinter to make a button. This code works and summons up a button that you can click and has a message on it. However, after summoning up the button the shell gives me a `TypeError`.

Seeing as the `TypeError` said i was missing the positional argument `self` i've tried to add self to my code. First i tried

```
btn.pack.self()
```

But that included a syntax error, so i tried this

```
btn.pack(self)
```

That also was a syntax error, how do i add the positional argument self without causing a syntax error?

The current code i'm using to create a button is:

```
btn = Button
**btn.pack()**
btn ["text"] = #whatever you want
def click():
   #whatever you want to make your button do
```

I hope to bypass the

> TypeError: pack_configure missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

without breaching a syntax error. I hope the output will not give me an error message in the shell.

Comment: Maybe you meant `btn=Button()` instead of `btn=Button`?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. But for starters, you need to create an instance of the class `Button` by `btn=Button()`.

Comment: Are you using a class ?? 
And Button needs ()

Comment: I've added a pair of brackets after btn = Button, but it still gives me the error message I originally asked the question about

Comment: Also @RobotMind I'm not using a class

Comment: Just realised I don't need a pair of brackets after btn.pack, and now it's sorted!